# Why parsing a String into Date in Java is slow? Can we accelerate it?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I am reading a text file containing dates, and I want to parse the Strings representing the dates into Date objects in java. What I notice is the operation is slow. Why? is there any way to accelerate it?
My file looks like:

```
2012-05-02 12:08:06:950, secondColumn, thirdColumn
2012-05-02 12:08:07:530, secondColumn, thirdColumn
2012-05-02 12:08:08:610, secondColumn, thirdColumn
```

I am reading the file line by line, then I am getting the date `String` from each line, then I am parsing it into a `Date` object using a `SimpleDateFormat` as follow:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(myFileInputStream);
BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String strLine;

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    ....Do things....
    Date myDateTime = (Date)formatter.parse(myDateString);
    ...Do things....
}
```

Comment: did you try using the same SimpleDateFormat instance throughout the entire file parse operation?

Comment: how have you determined that it is slow?

Comment: @Micheal, I just comment the operations related to the parse, the reading loop (line by line) is much quicker then.

Comment: @jtqhlborn yes the SimpleDateFormat is outside the reading loop, it is common for all the file.

Comment: The posted code is not enough to tell how you are handing the situation. How many lines do you have in your file, and how long is it taking?

Comment: If you are creating a new SimpleDateFormat instance in a loop everytime, your code will be slow. Creating SimpleDateFormat is expensive, try to define it outside the loop and resuse it.

[A nice article on SimpleDateFormat performance.][1]


  [1]: http://www.thedwick.com/2008/04/simpledateformat-performance-pig/

Comment: Define slow. How slow is slow?

Comment: @BheshGurung I just edited my code... my files contain about 3000 lines each.

Comment: Take a look at the code of SimpleDateFormat::parse(String) to see it's not an easy task. Especially the error handling is quite a bit of stuff. If your dates always look the same, you could parse them from the line yourself and fill the date instance accordingly. If that is faster I wouldn't dare to answer beforehand though.

Comment: @gresdiplitude I am actually defining my SimpleDateFormat outside the loop, I just edited my code.

Comment: @jayeff yes maybe is my only solution the... Thank you for this proposition

Comment: Have you measured just the parsing of the date? Or is it possible that the "Do things" parts are the real bottleneck?

Comment: @jayeff yes, 'Do things' is just dummy operations like incrementing an integer counter. I completely removed do Things. Without the date parsing reading the file line by line is just a matter of seconds, but with the parsing operation, it takes several minutes for one file.

Comment: If you have control over the creation of the file you want to read in, you could this: Add the date as a long when creating the file, read the long instead of parsing the above string and use the `Date(long date)` constructor.

Comment: I really wish people would stop mixing DataInputStream with BufferedReader.  Whoever started this meme ..... grrr.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The converting of dates and timezone is expensive.  If you can assume your date/times are similar to each other, you can convert the date and hours/minutes (or only dates if you use GMT) whenever minutes change and generate the seconds yourself.

This will call `parse` once per minute. Depending on your assumptions you could make it once per hours or once per day.

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String lastTime = "";
long lastDate = 0;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String myDateString = strLine.split(", ")[0];
    if (!myDateString.startsWith(lastTime)) {
        lastTime = myDateString.substring(0, pattern.length());
        lastDate = formatter.parse(lastTime).getTime();
    }
    Date date = new Date(lastDate + Integer.parseInt(myDateString.substring(pattern.length() + 1).replace(":", "")));
}
```

Comment: +1 for a code sample. OP - can we assume the file is in date/time order?

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

- Use ***java.time*** rather than legacy classes.
- Each parse of `String` to `LocalDateTime` with `DateTimeFormatter` takes less than **1,500 nanoseconds each** (0.0000015 seconds).

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Let's do a bit of micro-benchmarking to see just how slow/fast is parsing a date-time string in *java.time*.

## ISO 8601

The ISO 8601 standard defines sensible practical formats for textually representing date-time values. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

Use these standard formats instead of inventing your own, as seen in the Question.

## `DateTimeFormatter`

Define a formatting pattern to match your inputs.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS" );
```

We will parse each such input as a `LocalDateTime` because your input lacks an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Keep in mind that such values do *not* represent a moment, are *not* a point on the timeline. To be an actual moment requires the context of a zone/offset.

```
String inputInitial = "2012-05-02 12:08:06:950" ;
LocalDateTime ldtInitial = LocalDateTime.parse( inputInitial , f );
```

Let's make a bunch of such inputs.

```
int count = 1_000_000;
List < String > inputs = new ArrayList <>( count );

for ( int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++ )
{
    String s = ldtInitial.plusSeconds( i ).format( f );
    inputs.add( s );
}
```

Test harness.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
for ( String input : inputs )
{
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
}
long stop = System.nanoTime();
long elapsed = ( stop - start );
long nanosPerParse = (elapsed / count ) ;
Duration d = Duration.ofNanos( elapsed );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "Parsing " + count + " strings to LocalDateTime took: " + d  + ". About " + nanosPerParse + " nanos each.");
```

> Parsing 1000000 strings to LocalDateTime took: PT1.320778647S. About 1320 nanos each.

## Too slow?

So it takes about a second and a half to parse a million such inputs, on a MacBook Pro laptop with quad-core Intel i7 CPU. In my test runs, each parse takes about 1,000 to 1,500 nanoseconds each.

To my mind, that is not a performance problem.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: By far the best answer!! Great!!

Comment: Interestingly, "LocalDateTime.parse(..).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)" is actually slower than "SimpleDateFormat#parse(..).getTime()" using identical pattern ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"). By about 10-15% for me. I didn't expect that.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest writing a custom parser, which is going to be faster. Something like:

```
Date parseYYYYMMDDHHMM(String strDate) {
   String yearString = strDate.substring(0, 4);
   int year = Integer.parseInt(yearString);
   ...
```

Another way is using pre-computed hashmap of datetime (w/o millis) to unix-timestamp. Will work if there are no much distinct dates (or you can recompute it once the date flips over).